# How to create two virtual columns by different conditions from repeating row data using SQL?

Tags: mysqli

My database table has three columns: `[Date, Client, Value][1]`.

I want a new table with only three clients in it - "Technics", "Metal Inc", "Sunny Day" and two virtual total columns - "Price" / August, and "Price" / 2017.

What I tried so far and what I get: [Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujAl7.png)

Why does the "For August" total `SUM` goes down the next row, but not in a new column?
After all, my code says: `SELECT SUM(Value) AS 'For August'`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Union will give you rows instead of columns, for this case maybe you can use subqueries, try something like this

```
SELECT                          
t1.Client, SUM(t1.Value) AS 'For 2017', (SELECT SUM(t2.Value)FROM Test GROUP 
BY t2.Client)AS 'For August'
FROM Test AS t1
JOIN Test AS t2
    ON t1.Client = t2.Client
WHERE
t2.Date LIKE '%2017-08%'AND 
            (t2.CLient LIKE '%Technics%' OR t2.CLient LIKE 
            '%Metal Inc%' OR t2.CLient LIKE '%Sunny Day%')
            AND
(t1.CLient LIKE '%Technics%'
  OR t1.CLient LIKE '%Metal Inc%'
  OR t1.CLient LIKE '%Sunny Day%')
GROUP BY t1.Client
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I've tried what you proposed to me, but now I'm getting the second column filled with same value - with total SUM for all the three clients for August, instead of three different values for total SUM for all three clients for August.

Comment: Solved! finally got time to sit and check, there's gotta be a more elegant way, but it works :)

Comment: Once again - thank you for your time and for the answer! But please, do explain to me what are these t1 and t2, because I saw them in many topics before I post mine, and couldn't solve how they work. When I tried to use them, I always got an error... are they some sort of function? Do they have to be declared before this Sql code?

Comment: Alright, I tried your answer with phpMyAdmin and the results weren't right. The total numbers for August and for 2017 were too big. Maybe something wrong happens with the data when joining? P.S. the "t1" and "t2" worked great with phpMyAdmin, but didn't work with the Wordpress plugin I use to make SQL queries. Maybe this "t1" and "t2" interface isn't implemented in the plugin yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's weird is not working, I created the same table with 2 records for each client (one for August and one for September) and it was working fine. T1 and T2 are just aliases, in this case, a way to have the test table twice in the query without ambiguity

Comment: Thank you again for your trying. I'm still trying to figure it out, but the numbers I get are way too high using this code.
One more thing - my data is in float, not an integer. Can the mistake come from here? Do I have to do some parsing or something?